# Is a Hint a real Value?

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I,ve got a Script where Users can fill a Formular. This will be saved to a Database later.
If there are entrys in the database, they will be shown as a Hint in the EditText.

Now my Question: A User sees this hint in the formular and doesn't fill it(for Example with the same Again, because there is no need to change): Will the Hint count as a Value. Or is the EditText empty, when the User hits apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the Hint count as a Value

No.

> Or is the EditText empty, when the User hits apply?

Yes.

You may want the hint to tell the user what to type in, but not look like a valid value. For example, if you want the user to enter a formula, your hint might be `Formula` or `(enter a formula)`, not `E=mc^2`.

Comment: Wanted to show what he recently typed. Maybe he wanted to change something.

Answer (score 0):

No hint is not a value.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#hint

You can read there, it is value to be displayed to user when field is empty.